# TestNG with IE webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Hi Im a newbie to selenium, i was trying to use TestNG with IE webdriver, Now i cant instantiate the IE driver directly under the class (Not the main method). When i do that i get the below error:
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected instead
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token ""webdriver.ie.driver"", invalid

If i then put on a method with @BeforeSuite annotation, i need to pass the driver to every other test method in the class. Is there a way where i can by pass this passing the driver object.

Find below the sample code i am using:

```html
package FirstTestNGPackage;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestNGclass {
    
    @BeforeSuite 
    public void SetDriverPaths()
    {
        File IEDriver = new File("C:\\Users\\REDACTED\\Desktop\\SeleniumJars\\IE Driver\\IEDriverServerX64_2.44.0.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriver.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    
   
  @Test
  public void tester()
  {
      Driver.findElement(By.id("keywordInput")).sendKeys("REDACTED");
      Driver.findElement(By.id("keywordInput")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      Assert.assertEquals(Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search_results']/h1/span/strong")).getText(), "REDACTED");
  }
  
  @BeforeTest
  public void RMSLogin() 
  {
      Driver.navigate().to("REDACTED");  
          
  }
  
  @AfterTest
  public void closeBrowser()
  {
    
      Driver.quit();
      
  }
  
}
```

Comment: In this Code i see errors with every method as the Driver is not a public object in the class. Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with just creating a new driver in each test method?

Comment: Gimby: My tests are continuation types, As in every test wil start off where my previous test completed. Wouldn't having a driver instance in very test method make me repeat the earlier steps. If there is any better solution for this approach please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bad idea, unit tests should be isolated and independent from each other. if you want to do multiple tests that are continuous, put them in one test as they basically form one unit of work.

Comment: Gimby: I am performing a funtional testing of an application, where in i might be required to re use the same bit of functionality many times, this is why this breaking up of functionality (into smaller methods) and using them in sequences help. This is at least the approach we follow with other functional testing tools but with selenium i am not quite sure if we can do that.

Comment: Breaking up into isolated pieces of code is a perfectly fine idea, but breaking up into isolated tests is not.  You are very free to call those isolated pieces of code in sequence in a single test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

init you webdriver like this then you can use it in every method with `this.driver`.

```
public class FirstTestNGclass {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite 
    public void SetDriverPaths()
    {
        // ....
        this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    // ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution to this problem is to use a common driver class for your Test suite...so that we can use the same driver instance in all classes

**Common driver class**

```
public class Driver {

    public static WebDriver driver=null;



    public static WebDriver startdriver(String browser){


        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path");

        driver=new ChromeDriver();

        }else if(browser.equals("IE")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriver.getAbsolutePath());

        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();

        }
        return driver;

        }

    }
```

you can create a driver instance like this

```
Driver.startdriver("IE");
```

You can use the driver object like classname.instance

```
Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
```

Hope this helps you...if you have any queries Kindly get back